# How to add assigned variable to nextline in django template tags

Tags: django

I am currently writing a django template tag and it working well however it looks ugly since i have a lot of variables to assign and it is very long.

```
{% include "snippetSelect.html" with fieldName=form.status.name fieldValue=form.status.value fieldData=mission.status_as_dict fieldLabel="Select a Status" only %}
```

it there any way i can just add the assigned variable next line like this

```
{% include "snippetSelect.html" with \
 fieldName=form.status.name \
fieldValue=form.status.value \
fieldData=mission.status_as_dict \ 
fieldLabel="Select a Status" only %}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible out of the box, its a design decision.

[Here is a discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/vW23UhnV8BQ/tMfq6IjSpxkJ) where one of the core devs of Django explains why is not possible out of the box.

On the same discusion its proposed this:

> You *might* be able to make it work by adding the re.DOT_ALL flag to 
>   this re: [http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/**init**.py#L90](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/__init__.py#L90)